# Is there a difference between account's password and "host password" (in IBM Cloud)?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I created a following shell-script:

```
curl -X POST -u "my username" \
"https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/blah-blah-blah..." \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "url": "http://.../screenplay.txt",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {},
    "categories": {},
    "concepts": {},
    "entities": {},
    "keywords": {}
  }
}'
```

Then it asked me "Enter host password for user", and I did.

Result: {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}

I typed a password of an IBM account. Maybe I had to create another one just for API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the API Documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#analyze-text

You will need a service API Key, which you can obtain from IBM Cloud. The getting started tutorial from the service documentation shows you how - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial